# Can I only have const overloaded operator member function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm implementing a fraction class, and need to overload arithmetic operators.
The problem is, can I only implement a `const` version.

For example, addition:

```
Fraction operator+( const Fraction& other ) const;
```

Since both non-const, and const Fraction objects can call this function, do I still need to have an non-const `operator+` member function?

Answer (score 4):

`const` member functions can be called on non-`const` objects, so no, you don't need a non-`const` overload.

```
Fraction a, b;
Fraction c = a + b; // no problem
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, this kind of problem is better solved with a member `operator+=` and a nonmember `operator+`, like this:

```
class Fraction {
public:
    const Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction&);
};

Fraction operator+(const Fraction& lhs, const Fraction& rhs) {
    Fraction res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza - duh. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Very thoughtful! Thank you so much~~

Comment: @tobi303: True, but maybe question was not asked correctly....when you read it preciselly, you could undertand Curtis2 wants a `+` operator modifying the object (non-const). But it's true it is not obvious to understand that...

Answer (score 3):

No. You can call `const` methods over non-`const` objects, exactly as you can have `const` references bind to non-`const` objects. IOW, you can always pass an object that you can modify to code that promises not to modify it - there's no loss of safety. The opposite of course is not true - if you have a `const` object (=> an object you promised not to modify) you cannot pass it to code that doesn't adhere to this promise.